# Using setter in ViewModel using another property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I have the following `ViewModel` in my app and there is two `BirthDate` property (with / without time). When using `set { }` without body I encounter "Not using the value means that the accessor ignores the caller's intent which could cause unexpected results at runtime.". Then I added a private property and update set as `set { birthDateWithTime = value; }`. However, this time `birthDateWithTime` private property not sees to be used. Is there any mistake regarding to implementation below? I want to use both property separately and do not want to convert in JavaScript or code.

```
    public class DemoViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        private string birthDateWithTime;

        public string BirthDateWithTime {
            get { return BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm"); }
            set { birthDateWithTime = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it dependent exclusively in `BirthDate`?

Comment: What's the point of using empty `set`? Why just dont get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gabriel Llorico answer is correct. or maybe you can try another one.

```
private DateTime _birthDate;
public DateTime BirthDate{
   get{
      return _birthDate;
   }
   set{
     this._birthDate = value;
     this.BirthDateWithTime = this._birthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm");
   }
}
public string BirthDateWithTime{get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if it is solely dependent on `BirthDate`

```
public string BirthDateWithTime 
{
    get 
    { 
        return BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is only dependent to BirthDate. But what about setter? What if I need to set `BirthDateWithTime` property?

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a body-property style.

```
public string BirthDateWithTime => BirthDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set *BirthDateWithTime*, just set in the *BirthDate* property, so both are updated.